# Jquery steps "destroy" method is removing values given by User

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I have a Questionnaire form which is break down in steps by using JQuery steps plugin. In the process of form submission there is a certain point where i need to remove steps. When i use "destroy" JQuery steps method, the values filled in the form are lost.

For example:

```
<form>
<h3>Form A</h3>
<section>
    What is your name?<br/>
    <input type="text" value="" name="yourname" />
    What is your age group? <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="agegroup" value="1" />1-20
    <input type="radio" name="agegroup" value="2" />20-40
    <input type="radio" name="agegroup" value="3" />40-60
    <input type="radio" name="agegroup" value="4" />60+
   ......
   ......
<section>
</form>
```

I am using following steps:

1. Convert form into Jquery steps
2. Opening this form in Simple modal dialog.
3. User fill this form and close modal dialog.
4. I am using "destroy" jQuery steps method after closing dialog.
5. When user re-open simple modal dialog again then i am converting this form into JQuery steps. At that point user see that all filled values in the form are lost.

**The problem is at the 4th step. User have filled form at 3rd step. When i converted in back to original HTML, values given by user are lost.**

**Expected values at 4th step**

```
<h3>Form A</h3>
<section>
    What is your name?<br/>
    <input type="text" value="Ishwar Lal" name="yourname" />
    What is your age group? <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="agegroup" value="1" />1-20
    <input type="radio" name="agegroup" value="2" selected='selected' />20-40
    <input type="radio" name="agegroup" value="3" />40-60
    <input type="radio" name="agegroup" value="4" />60+
   ......
   ......
<section>
```

**but output is:**

```
<h3>Form A</h3>
<section>
    What is your name?<br/>
    <input type="text" value="" name="yourname" />
    What is your age group? <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="agegroup" value="1" />1-20
    <input type="radio" name="agegroup" value="2" />20-40
    <input type="radio" name="agegroup" value="3" />40-60
    <input type="radio" name="agegroup" value="4" />60+
   ......
   ......
<section>
```

**I need to remove JQuery steps from from with filled values.** I have read JQuery documentation but not found any idea about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you must to store data before you destroy the component. When you destroy a component it is destroyed, nothing else what to do.
If you store the data , then destroy object, and then initialize object with the data you stored. You can store in an array/object/variable, or you can store in sessionStorage / localStorage for use in other pages.

Comment: It is an alternative way to handle this. But do you know is there any method in jQuery steps to handle this issue ?

Comment: If you destroy a jquery object, you cannot use it. I think that you must to store data temporarily and when you initialize again jquery steps fill the fields with stored data.